# Irreversibility as an artificial concept and relationship with quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, quantum-information, reversibility

In my statistical physics classes we are following the book [Statistical physics of particles - by Mehren Kardar](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521873428) and we were viewing the derivation of the boltzmann equation and irreversibility . Anyone that has taken a look at the book knows that it is pretty aggressive with the mathematical expressions, so it's safe to say that I understood nothing of that mathematical jargon. However, what I did catch was that, in order to arrive to the conclusion of irreversibility of events, certain approximations had to be made. So it got me thinking: **Is irreversibility a mere artificial concept as a result of the adopted description of nature?**

In fact, if we used classical mechanics to describe a system of particles (however big it may be) the final equations would always be time reversible, that is, we would be associating a state to a point of the state space to an arbitrary precision and working from it getting to a reversible result. But from the moment that we work with a certain volume of the state space, and give a probabilistic description of the system, then our final result is obviously irreversible: we packed infinite states (assuming we are working with a continuous state space) in a volume and produced another infinite set of possible output states. But this is only so because we chose to work with probabilities! Along with this it comes a new perspective on entropy which, consequently, is also an artificial concept and not a natural one. It is often described as a *measure of disorder of the system*, but as Feynman suggests in his lectures on computation, entropy is related to our knowledge of the system. If there is a decrease of entropy in a system in doesn't mean that it is more organised, but instead that we have more information on what state it may be.

Now my second question comes in the light of quantum mechanics. All of my reasoning above seems to make sense to me and it felt like an epiphany, but quantum mechanics is at its core a statistical description of nature, **how does it allow reversible operations?** How come it allows reversible operators if it comes down to a statistical description?

Also, could we argue that classically (hence deterministic) there are **no irreversible** processes?

Comment: What concepts you don't consider to be artificial concepts in physics?

Comment: @nicoguaro that's fair, but we usually get concepts in physics that we can unquestionably relate to nature, to something inherent to it, for example the photons that make up light, and it's ondulatory nature. Surely it is weird, but nevertheless, real. The thing with irreversibility and entropy is that it was introduced as some natural phenomena when in fact tells us more about our human perspective than nature itself.

Comment: I have never "seen" a light wave. I experience colors, though. And there's a lot of modeling to tell me how that happens that makes sense.